# How to subset a dataframe based on one column level?

Tags: r

I would like to subset a df based on one level in a column, i.e. keep all rows that only contain this unique level within a column.

For this example I want a df with all columns that meet the criteria "blue" in column "D" without losing information. Whether that is subset, filter, etc.

```
A  B  C    D     E

1  2  3  "blue"  8
7  4  6  "red"   5
5  9  1  "green" 2
```

I have tried the variations of the following script:

```
newdf = subset(df, D == "blue")
newdf = subset(df, levels(D) == "blue")
```

Comment: `subset(df, D == "blue")` should have worked if you have a data frame.  Please add the output of `dput(df)` to your post.

Comment: Why don't you give exactly what output you're after and that way you're more likely to get the assistance you need.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would construct the output in a way that is clearer than my question, any suggestions for future reference? However, it turns out the confusion has been cleared away. The script I was using newdf = subset(df, D == "blue") works, there was an error in the df. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
newdf = df[df$D == "blue", ]
```